# Pygraphviz and fixed node positions

Tags: pygraphviz

How do I force pygraphviz to maintain fixed positions for my nodes. Assume that you have the following code

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division

import pygraphviz as pgv
from _operator import pos

A=pgv.AGraph()

A.add_node(1,color='red',pos="0,1") 
A.add_node(2,color='blue',pos="1,10")
A.add_node(3,color='yellow'pos="2,2")


A.add_edge(1,2,color='green')
A.add_edge(2,3)
A.add_edge(2,2,"1")
A.add_edge(1,3)

A.graph_attr['epsilon']='0.001'
print(A.string()) # print dot file to standard output
A.layout('dot') # layout with dot
A.draw('foo.pdf') # write to file
```

How do I force the nodes to show up at predetermined positions (0.1), (1,10 and respective (2,2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at http://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/pygraphviz-1.4rc1/reference/agraph.html and the signature for the draw method, it looks as if layout is only needed if pos is not present.

"
If prog is not specified and the graph has positions (see layout()) then no additional graph positioning will be performed."

In your case you could just try without using A.layout(). just A.draw('foo.pdf')